# Reading the correct Excel File in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an excel file using Apache POI. This is the first time I've done this, and am really struggling to get my program to use the correct file. My file is called TransactionList and I'm trying to read the results sheet as follows:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class GetTransactions {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("TransactionList.xlsx"));
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Results");
```

This then throws a " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError " error at line 14 and I really don't understand why. I may have incorrectly added the TransactionList file to my project but don't believe this is the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: May be jar file are broken or not all inclused ?

Comment: you should try `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);`

Comment: Please include the full exception text including the class-name that is not found. Otherwise it is hard to say what exactly is missing.

Comment: Can you include all exceptions messages !!